# Getting Lexer Error with AngularJS and ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm getting the following error at runtime:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 11-11 [\] in expression [[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?].
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<input type="text"
  class="form-control"
  name="amount"
  ng-pattern="{{ctrl.pattern}}"
  ng-model="ctrl.amount">
```

The assignment in my AngularJS controller is as follows:

```
ctrl.pattern = '[0-9]{1,4}(\\.[0-9]{1,3})?';
```

From what I understand AngularJS appends the ^ and $ at the beginning and end of regular expressions and that works great. The problem is that the regex literal in the middle of the expression is not being accepted.  I want to dot to be accepted as a literal and not as any character so I need a way to escape it yet the lexer does not to like it.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12913) but they are not going to fix it as according to them its a uncommon usecase.

---

Do it this way instead:

```
ctrl.pattern = /^[0-9]{1,4}([.][0-9]{1,3})?$/;
```

This way the regex will be evaluated as a regex object instead of a string parameter to `RegExp` in which case we will need to add `^`,`$`

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. I'm actually getting the regex from a translation file (need to replace the decimal separator depending on locale) so it has to be a string.  I was able to convert the string to a RegExp object via the constructor new RegExp() and thus use your solution.